# Sqlite3 datetime error

Tags: datetime, sqlite

When I try to update/insert records with a column type "datetime" I follow the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. However, when I insert for example `1991-01-01` and then run a select command it shows as `1989`, i.e. it counts the "-" as minus. How do I insert it so that it shows correctly?

Comment: How exactly do you insert that data?

Comment: `update person set dob = 1991-01-01 where id = 1;`

Comment: `update person set dob = '1991-01-01' where id = 1;` should do the trick.